# error Property 'getItem' does not exist in type 'string'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm using firebase to register links on a website, I'm trying to pass the uuid to create a sub collection, but without success, what can it be??

```
constructor(private af: AngularFirestore) {}

async add(urls: Urls, uuid: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.af.collection(`${this.collection}/${uuid.getItem('idCustomer')}/menu`).add({ ...urls });

    await this.getUrls(`${this.collection}/${uuid.getItem('idCustomer')}/menu`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `uuid` as a `string` and calling `.getItem('idCustomer')` on this string. A `string` however does not have a method called `getItem`.

It's quite unclear (to me) what you're trying to achieve. So I can tell you what's wrong, but no actual answer on how to solve the underlying issue.